# CQEngine String Query implementation

Tags: java, regex

CQEngine queries on String for instance StringEndsWith, StringContains ... are using iterative algorithm for matching operations do you have an idea why it is not done with regular expression instead?
I imagine that it is for performance purpose but it is not obvious for me that it will outperform a regex implementation.

Example StringEndsWith:

```
@Override
boolean matchesSimpleAttribute(SimpleAttribute<O, A> attribute, O object) {
    CharSequence attributeValue = attribute.getValue(object);
    return containsFragment(attributeValue, value);
}

@Override
boolean matchesNonSimpleAttribute(Attribute<O, A> attribute, O object) {
    for (A attributeValue : attribute.getValues(object)) {
        if (containsFragment(attributeValue, value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean containsFragment(CharSequence document, CharSequence fragment) {
    final int documentLength = document.length();
    final int fragmentLength = fragment.length();
    final int lastStartOffset = documentLength - fragmentLength;
    for (int startOffset = 0; startOffset <= lastStartOffset; startOffset++) {
        int charsMatched = 0;
        for (int endOffset = startOffset, j = 0; j < fragmentLength; j++, endOffset++) {
            char documentChar = document.charAt(endOffset);
            char fragmentChar = fragment.charAt(j);
            if (documentChar != fragmentChar) {
                break; // break inner loop
            }
            charsMatched++;
        }
        if (charsMatched == fragmentLength) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to optimize for a specific function than for a generic function.

A regex match is usually performed in two phases: compilation of the regex and the matching itself. Compilation transforms the regex into an expressions tree. During compilation each character of the regex is matched against the full range of regex special characters. After compilation the expression tree can be walked to match a string without having to reinterpret the entire regex each time.

So what do you think is faster? A stringEndWith compiled directly to byte/machine code or a regex "< string >$" which first needs to be compiled into an expression tree which then needs to be walked to match a string at the end of a string? At the very best case, which is more theory than practice, the *compiled* regex will match as fast as the stringEndsWith function. Meaning the compilation step is still slowing your program down.

Hope this clear things up.